# How copy the value type and length of a column of a table?

Tags: mysql, variables

I'm trying to copy the value type and length of a stored column to a temporary variable of a procedure.

The sintaxt of what I'm trying to do in PL SQL is

```
var table.column%TYPE;
```

I need to do it in MYSQL, any ideas of how can I do it?

Comment: why do u want to do it? do u want to use that for another query ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html).

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE,COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column';
```